Angular Velocity of 3D object rotating in space
For a sphere rotating about z axis, its angular velocity is rate of change of angle of a radius vector in xy plane with x axis or y axis. I understand this clearly. But consider a 3d body which is not symmetrical, now it has angular velocity vector which has 3 components. What does these three components signify and if instead the body is a symmetrical body like sphere then does that become my initial situation? I used to think that whenever angular velocity has 3 components, the resultant direction can be taken as the axis of rotation and whole body can be assumed rotating about that axis but after listening to some lectures I feel that, that is only possible only when the object shape is symmetrical like sphere but that is not the case when the object is asymmetrical. I just want to confirm that I am right.

Angular velocity comes from time derivative of rotation, the direction of the angular velocity vector can be interpreted as the direction of instantaneous rotation axis (changing it's direction as time evolves) and its magnitude as the instantaneous angle of rotation per unit time performed by the rigid body.
Time derivative of rotation tensor and angular velocity
A rotation in 3D is represented by a unitary tensors, namely rotation tensor. The rotation of a material vector $\Delta \mathbf{r}(t) = \mathbf{r}_P(t) - \mathbf{r}_Q(t)$ can be written as the action of the rotation tensor $\mathbb{R}$(t) on the material vector $\Delta \mathbf{r}_0$ in the original configuration,
$$\Delta \mathbf{r}(t) = \mathbb{R}(t) \cdot \Delta\mathbf{r}_0 \ .$$
During the rotation, the distance between two material points don't change and thus $|\Delta \mathbf{r}(t)|^2 = |\Delta \mathbf{r}_0|^2$ is constant, and thus
$$0 = \dfrac{d}{dt}|\Delta \mathbf{r}(t)|^2 = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left[ \Delta \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot  \Delta \mathbf{r}(t) \right] =  \dots$$
$$= \Delta \mathbf{r}_0 \cdot \left( \dot{\mathbb{R}}^T \cdot \mathbb{R} +  \mathbb{R}^T \cdot \dot{\mathbb{R}} \right) \cdot \Delta \mathbf{r}_0 \ .$$
From the last equation, it follows that the tensor $\Omega \hspace{-6pt} \Omega := \dot{\mathbb{R}} \cdot \mathbb{R}^T$ is antysimmetric, $= \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\times}$, being $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ the angular velocity vector.
Using $\mathbb{R}^T \cdot \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{I}$, it's possible to write the time derivative of the rotation tensor as $$\dot{\mathbb{R}} = \Omega \hspace{-6pt} \Omega \cdot \mathbb{R}$$.
Angular velocity and elementary rotation around instantaneous axis
The elementary displacement thus reads
$$\begin{aligned}\delta \Delta\mathbf{r}(t) & := \Delta \mathbf{r}(t+\delta t) - \Delta \mathbf{r}(t) = \\
& = \left[ \mathbb{R}(t+\delta t) - \mathbb{R}(t) \right] \cdot \Delta \mathbf{r}_0 \sim \\
& \sim \delta t \, \dot{\mathbb{R}}(t) \cdot \Delta \mathbf{r}_0 + o(\delta t) = \\
& = \delta t \, \Omega \hspace{-6pt} \Omega(t) \cdot \mathbb{R}(t) \cdot \Delta \mathbf{r}_0 + o (\delta t) = \\
& = \delta t \, \boldsymbol{\omega}(t) \times \Delta \mathbf{r}(t) + o(\delta t)
\end{aligned} \ .$$
This expression, neglecting higher-order terms, shows that:

$\Delta \mathbf{r}(t)$ is orthogonal to both $\boldsymbol{\omega}(t)$ and $\Delta \mathbf{r}(t)$
the abolute value of the elementary displacement is
$$|\delta \Delta \mathbf{r}(t)| = \delta t \, \omega(t) \, |\Delta \mathbf{r}(t)|\sin \phi(t) = \delta t \, \omega(t) \Delta r_{\perp \boldsymbol{\omega}} \ ,$$
with $\phi(r)$ the angle between $\boldsymbol{\omega}(t)$ and $\Delta \mathbf{r}(t)$ and $\Delta r_{\perp \boldsymbol{\omega}}$ is the projection of $\Delta \mathbf{r}(t)$ in a direction orthogonal w.r.t. $\boldsymbol{\omega}(t)$. This means that $\delta \Delta \mathbf{r}(t)$ is the displacement due to an elementary rotation $\delta \theta(t) = \delta t \, \omega(t)$ around the axis with direction $\hat{\boldsymbol{\omega}}$.



come on! anonymous downvoter, keep pushing! If it's 3 out of 3 by you alone, I'm so sorry for you

I don't understand why your clear answers are often downvoted. I answer similar questions and receive much fewer downvotes. If you suspect someone is targeting you, consider contacting the SE staff using the "contact" button at the bottom of the page. I personally don't think this is normal. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227845/401169 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268987/401169.

I don't know. I'm assuming there's only one crazy anonymous downvoter (or at least a very small bunch of them), since yesterday I received the usual downvote along with the question and the other 2 answers to that question. He probably had a bad day yesterday

From your reputation history I don't think it is a normal amount of downvotes to receive as there is nothing factually incorrect about your posts. That's why I think someone is targeting you. You can either ask the moderators to raise the issue to SE staff, or use the "contact" button to do so yourself.
